# Read a file line by line without moving the pointer from the beginning of a line in C

Tags: c

I have a problem where I need to access a file and read out every line where I have to perform a function on each character of the line. So far what I have tried is using this bit of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *stream;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    stream = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if (stream == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, stream)) != -1) {
        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    free(line);
    fclose(stream);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

However, when I try this,  I cannot perform the operations of the function on each character of the line as the character pointer has already moved to the end of each line after reading a line.

How can I access each character of a line while reading the file line by line. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: `ssize_t read` is BAD. `read` is a standard library function.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you not operate on the data in the `line` buffer within the `while` loop?

Comment: this while loop operates on the whole line at once, I want to perform the function on every char of each line.

Comment: then you can include an inner loop that loops through each char of the line you just read. But if you really want to read one char at a time you can use the [`read`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) function. As DYZ says, change the name of your `ssize_t read` variable to something else to avoid confusion

Comment: You have the `line`. All the characters are in that buffer. Use an inner loop to operate on each character. Otherwise, what is the point of reading `line` at all?

Comment: "cannot perform the operations of the function on each character of the line" is unclear as `line` is readily usable to operate on a _copy_ of the file's line.  State the operations needed, else this post is unclear.

Comment: Can I use getc(line) to get each character from the line?

Comment: You can use array indexing to get the characters in `line`.

Comment: Note: As `ssize_t` is a _signed_ integer type and could return -1, `printf("Retrieved line of length %zd :\n", read);` (zd vs. zu) is better.  Yet that is not specified to be right either.  `printf("Retrieved line of length %lld :\n", (long long) read);` will certainly work.

Comment: How would I do that @DavidBowling ? I am sorry, I am new to C.

Comment: Something like `for (size_t i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; i++) { //do something with line[i]};`

Comment: @DavidBowling `for (ssize_t i = 0; i < read; i++) foo(line[i])` would handle null characters and a `read == -1` situation unlike `line[i] != '\0'`.

Comment: @chux-- Yes, that sounds better.

Comment: Thank You everyone!

Comment: between these two lines: `if (stream == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` should be the line: `perror( "fopen for file.txt failed" );  so the reason (as the OS see it) is also output, to stderr.

Comment: when the `while()` loop exits, call `perror()` so the reason for the exit of the while() loop is output to stderr